# Launch app from non clickable uri

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I have a custom URL that is a deep link to an app. The scheme is not http or https and as a result it appears always in plaintext. 
Filling the chrome address bar with it does not result in anything other than a google search.
Question: how can I somehow pass this string to Android to interpret it as an intent?
I was wondering if there is something similar to command->run that PCs have.
Note: I know I can use adb. I am interested in a way that is not with adb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The criteria for what constitutes a clickable link depends on the app in which it viewed. Custom URIs often don't qualify as links, which is why you're seeing it in plaintext.

The Chrome address bar is a different issue: the Chrome team [has decided that nothing input there will ever redirect to another app](https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/) (obviously I disagree with this decision, but they are pretty convinced it is better for users). To see correct link behavior in Chrome, you'd actually need to *click* a link with the custom URI scheme behind it.

To achieve what you want, you need to use a regular `http://` or `https://` URL, and then wrap the custom URI path inside a redirect. If you're not interested in building this yourself (you shouldn't be!), look into services like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) or Firebase Dynamic Links.

Comment: So if someone has given me a string that constitutes a uri there is absolutely *no* way that I as a user I am able to launch the relevant app unless I use an adb bridge?

Comment: Also what do you mean by wrapping in a redirect? Is it a form of URL or do I need a server to actually send some page with the uri? I didn't understand could you please elaborate?

Comment: As a user, generally no. You'd have to find an app that can interpret a custom URI string as an active link. The redirect could be implemented as either javascript or HTTP (302/307), but yes it would need to be sent from a server. That's where Branch or Dynamic Links come in :)

Comment: So if chrome sees the custom uri in the location of the 302 it then launches the app i.e. first checks that an app has registered for that scheme?

Comment: That is the basic concept, yes. If the app doesn't launch (because it isn't installed), you redirect to the store